# Is there a way to skip empty Google sheet values and continue with the next row in focus? Partially working script included

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, google-sheets, data-structures

Below is a python script that will send an email to an address listed in the same row. My information/message is in column #2, and my target email address is in column #6. The script is working. However, when there is no email address in column #6 (blank cell), it skips to the next available email address and sends the wrong text for column #2 (it sends column 2 text where there's no email address in the row). So, the wrong message is sent...  The only way I can make it work is if there are values in each and every cell and I don't skip any cells in column #6. I don't know how to do it otherwise. Does anybody know how the script can be modified so that I can send emails only when there's an available email address, skip if there's no available email address, and ensure that only values from the correct row are sent? Here's the code I have so far. Also, please see the attached image.

[image: Sheet Example]

```
class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            return super(DatetimeEncoder, obj).default(obj)
        except TypeError:
            return str(obj)


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('', scope)


testtime = datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y AT %H:%M:%S.')

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("log").worksheet("emaillist")

emaillist = [item for item in wks.col_values(6)[1:] if item]
for item in emaillist:
    print(item)

messageinfo = [item2 for item2 in wks.col_values(2)[1:] if item2]
for item2 in messageinfo:
    print(item2)

import yagmail

yag = yagmail.SMTP("x@gmail.com", "x")


for i in range(len(emaillist)):
    email = emaillist[i]
    body = "test"


    yag.send(
        to=[email],
        subject="Inquiry " + testtime,
        contents=messageinfo,
    )

print("Done")
```

Edit: I have a semi solution. maybe not the most elegant. Would still appreciate your input:

```
def emails(wks):
    for row in wks.get_all_records():
        if row["EMAIL"] and row != "":
            yield row["EMAIL"]

to_emails = list(emails(wks))


print(to_emails)

def message(wks):
    for row in wks.get_all_records():
        if row["MESSAGETEXT"] and row["EMAIL"] != "":
            yield row["MESSAGETEXT"]


to_message = list(message(wks))
print(to_message)
```

This splits it into two lists... Still testing this out

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
def emails(wks):
    for row in wks.get_all_records():
        if row["EMAIL"] and row != "":
            yield row["EMAIL"]

to_emails = list(emails(wks))


print(to_emails)

def message(wks):
    for row in wks.get_all_records():
        if row["MESSAGETEXT"] and row["EMAIL"] != "":
            yield row["MESSAGETEXT"]


to_message = list(message(wks))
print(to_message)
```